# Como denunciar uma suspeita manipulação de votos sem expor o usuário?

Tags: debate, suporte

Como posso denunciar uma suspeita manipulação de votos sem expor o usuário?

Um usuário fez um comentário aparentemente "sensato" e o outro tentou justificar o "erro" comentado, este que justificou o "erro" recebeu um voto no comentário logo em seguida, como não foi na pergunta ou resposta ignorei e imaginei que alguém concorde mesmo com o usuário.

No entanto eu fiquei na duvida se eu notar uma situação parecida, tanto para resposta, perguntas e comentários.

Devo *sinalizar* para o moderador na *pergunta*, *resposta* ou *comentário* que notei a possível manipulação?

Ou existe outro canal para isto?

Comment: Acho que você deve mandar [email](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact) pelo site ou email do [gabe](http://stackexchange.com/users/5960/gabe) com as suspeitas.

Comment: Manipulação de "um" voto, ou de atividades suspeitas no geral?

Comment: @Math um voto foi o que eu vi, por isto é suspeita, se eu notar com maior frequência vindo do mesmo usuário eu acredito que devo denunciar.

Comment: Você pode mandar email como disse o @rray, ou sinalizar a postagem explicando o motivo e indicando as evidências

Comment: @bfavaretto conforme o Math como as sinalizações para moderador não vão para a fila e sim diretamente para os moderadores, então este me parece o melhor caminho! Obrigado

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pode fazer uma denúncia sinalizando uma publicação do usuário.

Por mais que a manipulação consista em vários usuários interagindo em diversas publicações diferentes, apenas uma sinalização personalizada explicando suas suspeitas já basta.

As sinalizações personalizadas não passam pela fila de análise comum e vão para a fila de análise da moderação, lá ela é analisada por humanos (os mods) que poderão investigar o caso mais a fundo mas ainda assim com total discrição.

Por mais que de repente suas suspeitas estejam erradas, se sua sinalização foi bem intencionada marcaremos ela como "útil".

Comment: Ótimo, então este é realmente o canal correto. Obrigado supermath e superbfavaretto (moderadores e seus superpoderes)!