# Quem está votando?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-recusado

Hoje eu vi uma pergunta feita pelo [@Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4042/como-denunciar-uma-suspeita-manipula%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-votos-sem-expor-o-usu%C3%A1rio?rq=1) em que mostra se alguém está votando em si mesmo, mas através de outro usuário.

### Como isso seria possível?

Existem várias maneiras de você votar em usa própria pergunta/resposta, como por exemplo entrar com um outro IP (Tor Browser faz isso), em outro usuário e achar a pergunta e votar nela. Isso está errado, correto?

### O que poderia ser feito?

Poderiam criar um privilégio, ou algo para os moderadores ver quem está votando nas perguntas e respostas, se fulano está votando direto nas perguntas do mesmo cidadão **iria levantar uma suspeita**, facilitando uma possível investigação sobre o que está acontecendo.

### "Eu não vou com a sua cara"

*Ah, eu não gosto do Luquinhas, não vou com a cara dele, vou dar um downvote nessa perguntinha e resposta dele aqui* - Isso é uma coisa que infelizmente acontece, além de estar investigando quem está fazendo **Free Vote** poderia identificar esses *revoltadinhos* observando se ele fica dando downvote em suas perguntas e respostas.

Bom, tá ai um recurso que seria útil para gerenciar a moderação entre votos...

Comment: Eles fazem algo como criar uma outra conta (abra uma janela anonima ou navegador diferente), ganham reputação nessa nova conta pra ter o privilégio de também poder votar e começam a dar upvotes na sua conta padrão. Se notar isto a unica coisa que dá pra fazer é uma `flag` nas perguntas ou respostas que receberam upvotes que você notou, então os moderadores vão monitorar e pelo log de IPs vão descobrir quem é e suspender.

Comment: Os moderadores têm algumas ferramentas para identificar fraude de votos. Em caso de suspeita, você também pode sinalizar alguma postagem da pessoa e dar detalhes para a equipe de moderação. Mas, hoje, somente os gerentes de comunidade como o Gabe podem ver quem votou em quem. Agora, quer saber? Poderia ser bom se os votos fossem realmente abertos. Acredito que não o sejam para evitar discussões entre os usuários (o que é mesmo muito provável que ocorra), mas poderia uma experiência interessante.

Comment: @bfavaretto sim, no inicio isso ter muita reclamação, mas com o tempo o pessoal iria se acostumar, parece que seria bem útil a comunidade.

Comment: Não acho uma boa ideia expor todos os votos, infelizmente eu sei que tem gente que abusa do sistema de votação e não vota pelos motivos certo, mas também tem muita gente que não sabe levar numa boa votos negativos. Isso só faria com que as pessoas não votassem negativo mais, por medo de represália, e olha que isso já acontece, dê um -1 e justifique pra você ver... Muita gente leva pro pessoal, perguntas e respostas ruins não seriam filtradas, fora desentendimentos entren membros que iria aumentar.

Comment: A [ideia do luiz](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4865/dever%C3%ADamos-qualificar-os-votos) até agora é a que eu acho a mais adequada, dar um pouco mais de dificuldade a quem vai negativar, com certeza inibe votos dados de qualquer jeito, e justificar algo feito com más intenções normalmente faz com que a pessoa pense um pouco.

Comment: Eu sei que não vai acontecer mas se os votos fossem abetos, um monte de problemas seriam solucionados, até mesmo os possíveis problemas que essa modificação poderia causar seriam solucionados pela transparência. Eu acho que os negativos diminuiriam e os positivos aumentariam. A pessoa votaria mais na certeza. Se ele votar errado, todo mundo vai saber. Se a pessoa abusar, todo mundo vai saber. Não seria livre de problemas, mas seria interessante ver.

Comment: Eu estou votando! E vou parar imediatamente assim que meu voto deixar de ser anônimo. É uma das funcionalidades que adoro aqui na rede [se], por favor, me deixa em paz pra votar como quiser, não sou nenhum vândalo nem um descerebrado. Vamos correr atrás dos fraudadores e deixar os cidadãos normais em paz. ¡¡Obrigado!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Obviamente eu não posso entrar em detalhes sobre como exatamente funciona a detecção de votos irregulares (seja em sí mesmo, seja em outros). Mas os moderadores, junto com os gerentes de comunidade, tem ferramentas suficientes pra detectar as irregularidades.

Dito isso, apesar de entender que votos abertos poderiam coibir certos abusos, os custos e riscos para o bem estar da comunidade são muito altos. Além disso, um dos principios fundamentais do nosso sistema é de que seus acertos são públicos, mas seus erros são privados. Por isso os votos são invalidados silenciosamente, e por isso as mensagens de moderação são privadas e ninguém é alertado.

A ideia é que todo mundo tem a chance de errar, e não precisa pagar pelas consequências do que fez pra sempre. Acreditamos que apontar o dedo pra quem fez algo de errado não é um comportamento construtivo ou desejado nas nossas comunidades. E isso é muito difícil de se manter se tivéssemos downvotes ou upvotes dados de forma pública.

Como eu disse, a ideia pode até funcionar por um período mas criaria problemas muito maiores do que ela se propõe à resolver.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Concordo plenamente com o problema da ausência de comentários. Mas esse é um problema muito mais cultural do que sistêmico na comunidade e, portanto, a melhor maneira de resolvê-lo é com a comunidade se policiando e se conscientizando. Tornar comentários obrigatórios pode ter efeitos indesejados também, como excesso de feedback similar, ou a diminuição de downvotes em coisas claramente danosas (como spam)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento concordo contigo. Como o Gabe falou, é um problema cultural, mas não é o SO que vai conseguir mudar algo foi enraizado nas pessoas no decorrer do tempo. Eu sou um dos que assumo que voto sem justificar(por mais que fique com vontade de fazê-lo), pois antes justificava todos os downvotes, até ser vitima de serial downvote 2 vezes em menos de 15 dias. Critica é algo dificil de se assimilar, não são todos que tem maturidade e sabedoria para lidar com elas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Um problema cultural é um problema da nossa comunidade. O comportamento humano pode se adaptar a diversos costumes e hábitos, e cabe à cada grupo de pessoas incentivar o comportamento que desejam na sua comunidade, e desmotivar os que são nocivos à ela.